# How do I translate a views field to lowercase and with spaces replaced with dashes but not make it a link?

Tags: views

I've got a link that surrounds some code (jquery hexagons). I'd like to be able to just print out the link.

The solution

Firstly, 2 copies of the 'studio name field'. The second set to 'rewrite as link' with the translations.

Secondly, 'exclude from display' both fields.

Thirdly. Custom text to print out the hexagon.

```
<div class="comb studio-comb">
<div class="front-content">
    <a href="/studio/[field_studio_name_1]">
        <h2>[field_studio_name]</h2>
        <hr class="break">
        [field_studio_address]
    </a>
</div>
<div class="back-content">
      <a href="/studio/[field_studio_name_1]">
        <h2>[field_studio_name]</h2>
        <hr class="break">
        [field_studio_address]
    </a>
</div>
```

If I use the 'rewrite as link' replacement then I get

```
 <a href="/studio/<a href=... >">
```

If I use the raw version I am stuck with

```
<a href="/studio/My Studio">
```

Here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atbcpmqu/) with a views export that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you please add what field you have and what you want in output. I will send export file of view.

Comment: Hi @PankajYogi The 'custom text' is what I want. It is easy to show, I'll attach an export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want link all output with studio/my-studio .First convert My studio to lowercase then rewrite as link  custom text.

Think My studio is [field_studio_name_1] .Convert this to lowercase. Then rewrite as link custom text like this .

[image]

Comment: ah - of course. You can rewrite in the link text too. Nice.

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: Yes - nicely https://www.yogahive.com.au/students/find-the-right-yoga-class-for-you

Comment: Great Is that Your personal account on drupal.stackexchange ?